# Beginner needing needs pointing in the right direction with the ActivityResultLauncher

Tags: android, android-intent

I am currently learning Android and the book I am currently using, uses startActivityForResult has been removed. I don't understand the replacement code. I would be grateful for any help. Even if it's just a little bit of help. When i click to go on the  second activity (CheatActivity) the app crashes,

This is the MainActivity

```
    // create the mCheatButton
    mCheatButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.cheat_button);
    mCheatButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            openSomeActivityForResult (MainActivity.this);
        }
    });
}

    public void openSomeActivityForResult (Context packageContext) {
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                    }
                }
            });

    //Create Intent
    // create an intent
    boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank [mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();
    Intent intent = CheatActivity.newIntent (MainActivity.this, answerIsTrue);
    someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
}
```

This is the CheatActivity

```
   public static Intent newIntent (Context packageContext, boolean answerIsTrue)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent (packageContext, CheatActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra (EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
    return intent;
}

public static boolean wasAnswerShown (Intent result)
{
    return result.getBooleanExtra (EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, false);
}

     private void setAnswerShownResult (boolean isAnswerShown)
{
    Intent data = new Intent ();
    data.putExtra (EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, isAnswerShown);
    setResult (RESULT_OK, data);
}
```

Here is the stack trace.

```
   2022-07-14 22:43:42.928 23134-23134/com.michaeldoughty.android.geo_quiz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.michaeldoughty.android.geo_quiz, PID: 23134
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner com.michaeldoughty.android.geo_quiz.MainActivity@f723e0d is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.
    at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.register(ActivityResultRegistry.java:123)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.registerForActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:682)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.registerForActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:691)
    at com.michaeldoughty.android.geo_quiz.MainActivity.openSomeActivityForResult(MainActivity.java:278)
    at com.michaeldoughty.android.geo_quiz.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:182)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5340)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21606)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: "When i click to go on the second activity (CheatActivity) the app crashes" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the crash. If you do not understand the stack trace, add it to your question so we can see it!

Comment: I have put the stack trace in now.

Comment: Move `someActivityResultLauncher` to be field of your class, rather than a variable inside of your `openSomeActivityForResult()` method. See [this](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/blob/master/ContactPicker/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/samplerj/contact/MainActivity.java#L34-42) bit of code from [one of my free books](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack),

Comment: Cheers, I will try that tommorow

Comment: Do i leave the intent in there

Comment: If you mean `ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>`, yes, you keep that. If you mean your code starting from `//Create Intent`, that code does not move and remains in your `openSomeActivityForResult()` method.

Comment: Did you get a chance to [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)? It explains exactly how to `registerForActivityResult` and `launch`.